# AD new user account: create from scratch or copy existing user?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I can't seem to find a consensus for this online. My colleague who is writing our documentation has put that it is "best practice" to create our AD accounts new and from scratch....I have never heard or read this anywhere when studying AD. Every single job I've had (including one at a MSP) we copied existing accounts to make the process more streamlined, more foolproof and just generally take some of the human error screw-ups out of the process.

I really think the only argument for creating an AD user from scratch could be to ensure they are not over-provisioned with rights and group memberships...? But of course that could simply be fixed after account creation. Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: There's no best practice and this is completely subjective and opinion based. Use whichever method best suits your operational work flow.

Comment: Keep in mind copying users will set attributes you may not need or be aware of on the new account. For this reason, prefer creating new each time. Write a PowerShell script to make the process repeatable.

Answer (score 6):

If you're any larger than a small business, the answer should be **neither**.

There are a bunch of tools out there to manage the lifecycle of identities and ideally you choose one of these and implement it (again, unless you're a small business, then this is overkill). Microsoft Identity Manager and Azure AD Provisioning Services can connect to external systems (Think HRIS systems like Workday) and take information from there and use it to provision resources in other systems like Active Directory.

It's possible for someone in HR to add a new employee and all related data to their HR system, and for something like MIM to take all of that info (name, location, job title, manager, etc) and automatically create the user based off of that info and place them in the correct security groups for that job role.

Answer (score 3):

In my eyes, it is better to create users from scratch.

By copying, chances are high that you copy attributes, information and permissions that you did not want to copy. And even if you check this after the copy process, some things may slip through - believe me, I had this. We are doing the copy thing, and I do not like it.

I belive the best way for user creation is a powershell script that does the creation and fills all attributes needed, combined with a well structured group hierachy and a consequent permission handling based on these groups. Like this the creation of new users can be done much faster then copying and checking what needs to be changed after.

Comment: I don't really agree about creating AD users from scratch, but I absolutely agree about the PS script.